# Sample randomly within cutoff in tibble R

Tags: r, random, tidyverse, tibble

I have a tibble with 100 points in R, below:

`preds <- tibble(x=1:100, y=seq(from=0.01,to=1,by=0.01))`

And I want to randomly sample 20 observations with values less than 0.5. Currently, I can select the first 20 observations by:

```
number_of_likely_negatives<-20

likely_negatives <- preds %>% 
    arrange(y) %>% 
    slice(1:number_of_likely_negatives)
```

But how can I randomly select 20 observations with y values below 0.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may `filter` the 'y' values before `slice`ing

```
likely_negatives <- preds %>% 
    arrange(y) %>% 
    filter(y < 0.5) %>%
    slice(sample(seq(number_of_likely_negatives), 20, replace = FALSE))
```

We can also use `slice_sample`

```
preds %>% 
   arrange(y) %>%
   filter(y < 0.5) %>% 
   slice_sample(n = number_of_likely_negatives)
```

Comment: In the second one, you don't need the `arrange` if you were going to `filter` anyways.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
sample_n(preds[preds$y < 0.5,], 20)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 20 × 2
       x     y
   <int> <dbl>
 1    42  0.42
 2    18  0.18
 3    44  0.44
 4    17  0.17
 5     7  0.07
 6    38  0.38
 7    23  0.23
 8    27  0.27
 9    20  0.2 
10     6  0.06
11    35  0.35
12    11  0.11
13     9  0.09
14    34  0.34
15    30  0.3 
16    29  0.29
17    39  0.39
18     3  0.03
19    13  0.13
20    47  0.47
```

Comment: This is the most direct solution; I think you should replace 20 with `number_of_likely_negatives`.

Answer (score 1):

A direct answer:

```r
preds %>% 
  slice(
    sample.int(which(y>threshold)[1], size = number_of_likely_negatives, replace = TRUE)
  )
```